# Is the concept of forking (source code) a relevant term in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: fork, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hard or Soft forking of blockchain code (such as Bitcoin and Ethereum) has caused a significant change (and headache) for shareholders of those blockchains.

My question is does hard or soft forking and the process of voting for a fork is a relevant concept in Hyperledger projects? Does Hyperledger Fabric allows the nodes to create a fork and run the fork?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, if you change the source code you can do whatever you want - hard or soft fork, and since Fabric is a permissioned blockchain - you have to coordinate with the members of the channel before you do such a thing - else you'll have a state fork.

Comment: Thank you!, are you referring to state or stale fork?

Comment: stale fork? what s that?